# How to install the optional LAMMPS package DPD-REACT in MacOS?

Tags: lammps, software-assistance, apple-operating-system

I have installed LAMMPS on my mac-pro (OS Monetery), using [this](https://docs.lammps.org/Install_mac.html).

I installed Homebrew and then LAMMPS. I need to install [DPD-REACT](https://docs.lammps.org/Packages_details.html#pkg-dpd-react) package. I tried `-D PKG_DPD-REACT=on` in my terminal following [this](https://docs.lammps.org/Packages_details.html#pkg-dpd-react), but it said `command not found: -D` .

I also tried the `make` command, and got: `make yes-DPD-REACT make: *** No rule to make target yes-DPD-REACT'.  Stop`.

**I am not sure how to install my DPD-REACT package. Can anybody help me with that please?**

Comment: I think your links relate to two different methods of installation. The first link refers to installing a binary of LAMMPS and in that case I don't think you have the ability to link it with other programs since it is already built (though it may already be included in the executable). If the program you are looking for is not included, you need to build LAMMPS from source with the appropriate complier flags, which are the commands mentioned in your second link. Someone who knows more about LAMMPS may be able to help you more.

Comment: Delaram, did you figure this out? Please update us! Is it just LAMMPS that you want to install on MacOS? The title just says "a package" which is very vague.

Comment: Hello , yes I wanted to install a package of Lammps after installing the LAMMPS. I figured it out. Tyberius answer helped me.

Answer (score 1):

The OP has figured out the answer to the question:

> "Hello , yes I wanted to install a package of Lammps after installing the LAMMPS. I figured it out. Tyberius answer helped me"

based on a comment by Tyberius:

> "I think your links relate to two different methods of installation. The first link refers to installing a binary of LAMMPS and in that case I don't think you have the ability to link it with other programs since it is already built (though it may already be included in the executable). If the program you are looking for is not included, you need to build LAMMPS from source with the appropriate complier flags, which are the commands mentioned in your second link. Someone who knows more about LAMMPS may be able to help you more."